# ocaml unbound constructor type error from type definition

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to use dates and times in my code, so I have loaded the Calendar Lib using opam. I have a simple piece of code that demonstrates the problem (example.ml):

```
open CalendarLib

type datefun = date -> int

let run_datefun (f : datefun) (d : date) = (f d)

let () =
  let mydate = make 2016 5 23 in
  printf "Day of week = %i" run_datefun days_in_month mydate
```

As far as I can see the Calendar days_in_month method has a type signature of `date -> int`.

When I try and compile this code (`corebuild -pkg calendar example.byte`) I get the following error:

```
File "example.ml", line 3, characters 15-19:
Error: Unbound type constructor date
```

which seems to me like the compiler is looking for a Date constructor for a date type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions and datatypes you'd like to use are inside the [`Date` module](http://calendar.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc/index_modules.html), so rephrasing your code we get (I've also taken the liberty of rewriting the output phrase and inserted the missing parentheses):

```
open CalendarLib

type datefun = Date.t -> int

let run_datefun (f : datefun) (d : Date.t) = (f d)

let () =
  let mydate = Date.make 2016 5 23 in
  Printf.printf "# of days in current month = %i\n" (run_datefun Date.days_in_month mydate)
```

A little test (by the way, you don't need `corebuild` for this):

```
$ ocamlbuild -pkg calendar example.ml example.byte
Finished, 3 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.

$ _build/calendar.byte
# of days in current month = 31
```